# Spring Application.Properties and Application-dev.properties files parameter conflict

Tags: spring, spring-boot, application.properties

profile logic in my application.properties file.My problem is when I use -dev ,it reads value from application-dev.properties.But I have same key which does not exist in my application-dev.properties but exist on application.properties,spring continue to read values from application.properties

```
application.properties
myfirstkey=x
mysecondkey=x

application-dev.properties
mysecondkey=dev

-Dspring.profiles.active=dev (// I pass profile value and see result by the way)
```

Output mysecondkey dev ,it is okay no problem 
Output myfirstkey is x (my expectation is empty),but it doesnt exist in application-dev.properties?Is there anyway to prevent application.properties read

Answer (score 0):

Well, `application.properties` are basically your 'default' .properties and you can't just (on a case-per-case basis) disable them, so the fix would be to do this in your -dev.properties.

```
myfirstkey=
```